# Unable to import google logging metric using terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created in `terraform` the following logging metric resource

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "proservices_run" {
  name   = "user/proservices-run"
  filter = "resource.type=gae_app AND severity>=ERROR"
  project = "${google_project.service.project_id}"
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = "DELTA"
    value_type  = "INT64"
  }
}
```

I have also on Stackdriver a custom metric named `user/proservices-run`.

However the following two import attempts fail:

```
$ terraform import google_logging_metric.proservices_run proservices-run

google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Importing from ID "proservices-run"...
google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Import complete!
  Imported google_logging_metric (ID: proservices-run)
google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Refreshing state... (ID: proservices-run)

Error: google_logging_metric.proservices_run (import id: proservices-run): 1 error occurred:
    * import google_logging_metric.proservices_run result: proservices-run: google_logging_metric.proservices_run: project: required field is not set
```

```
$ terraform import google_logging_metric.proservices_run user/proservices-run

google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Importing from ID "user/proservices-run"...
google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Import complete!
  Imported google_logging_metric (ID: user/proservices-run)
google_logging_metric.proservices_run: Refreshing state... (ID: user/proservices-run)

Error: google_logging_metric.proservices_run (import id: user/proservices-run): 1 error occurred:
    * import google_logging_metric.proservices_run result: user/proservices-run: google_logging_metric.proservices_run: project: required field is not set
```

Using

```
Terraform v0.11.14
```

and

```
provider.google = 2.11.0
provider.google-beta 2.11.0
```

**edit**: I noticed the `project: required field is not set` in the error message, I added the field `project` in my TF code, however the outcome is still the same.

Comment: Can you edit your Terraform code in your question to be a [mcve] please? It's not clear what you're doing wrong without that part.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you were talking about, but I added the `project` field in the resource declaration, given that the error message was hinting that the failure was due to the `project` value not being set; however I am still getting the same error message when trying to import

Comment: Can you correct your examples given and make sure that it is genuinely reproducible on the import failures too? It looks like you've edited them because you're apparently running `terraform google_logging_metric.proservices_run proservices-run` instead of `terraform import google_logging_metric.proservices_run proservices-run`.

Comment: sorry about that just edited the import statement too

Comment: What happens if you define the project in the provider block instead of in the resource?

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately because this is actually called via `terragrunt` and the respective code is in another repo.

Comment: Temporarily add it while you are importing and then remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue trying to import a log-based metrics.

The solution was to set the env-var `GOOGLE_PROJECT=<your-project-id>` when running the command.

```
GOOGLE_PROJECT=MyProjectId \
  terraform import \
  "google_logging_metric.create_user_count" \
  "create_user_count"
```

Comment: I can confirm that; had worked around the issue the way you are describing but neglected to post the answer.

Comment: if you set the project for the provider it'll work also, example: `provider "google" { project = "MyProjectId"}`. I think it's a bug in terraform import, since in the resource I wanted to import the project field was specified.